# SSH access without home and redirected to another directory

Tags: ssh

I set up a server with 2 users, there is no FTP access only SSH one.
I want to add a new user. 
It will be easy with a

```
sudo adduser foo
```

But, i want foo to be redirected to /home/user1/foo when login with SSH.

I don't really need foo to have a /home, but if he got one it's ok !

I read the man pag but didn't find any clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, let's look at the man page again: http://linux.die.net/man/8/adduser

```
sudo adduser --home /home/user1/foo foo
```

creates the user and sets his home directory to /home/user1/foo